# Is there a "code less" way to construct this JS loop?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I just know there's a simpler, better way to do this. Will eventually append <select> options with these values (e.g. 01:30, 02:45, 10:15, etc.)

```
var arrHours=[]
var i=0, j=0, k=0;
for (i=0;i<=23;i++)
{
    for(j=0;j<=45;j=j+15)
    {
        var m,n;
        m=i.toString();
        n=j.toString();
        if(m=="0")
        {
            m="00";
        }
        if(m.length<2)
        {
            m="0"+m;
        }
        if(n=="0")
        {
            n="00";
        }
        arrHours.push(m+":"+n);
    }
}
for(k in arrHours)
{
    $("#preview4").append(arrHours[k]+"<BR>");
}
```

*ps. I prefer the semicolon*. ;)

Answer (score 4):

I would do it like this. Note how the zero-padding is encapsulated in a function and how the double loops are turned into a single loop by using modulo and integer division. Also, the `var`s are pre-declared as is considered good style in JavaScript.

```
function zeroPad(number) {
    if (number <= 9) {
        return "0" + number;
    } else {
        return number;
    }
}

var i, hour, minute,
    arrHours = [];
for (i = 0; i < 60 * 24; i += 15) {
    hour = Math.floor(i / 60);
    minute = i % 60;
    arrHours.push(zeroPad(hour) + ":" + zeroPad(minute));
}
```

Comment: +0: I think it's much less readable to merge the two `for`s and use modulo and division; the rest of the suggestions are great though, good job.

Comment: It seems like this would also be faster by looping only once as well, right? Or, at the very least, consume less memory. This makes more sense to me than what I was doing. Thanks Raba.

Answer (score 4):

I would unroll the minutes loop to make code more readable:

```
var times = [], hour, i;

for (i = 0; i < 24; ++i) {
    hour = (i < 10 ? '0' : '') + i;
    times.push(hour + ':00');
    times.push(hour + ':15');
    times.push(hour + ':30');
    times.push(hour + ':45');
}
```